# Why i'am getting Multiple markers at this line error in my ejb3

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a stateless ejb3 which is working fine, but eclipse is showing the following error beside the Ejb class name :

Multiple markers at this line

```
- CHKJ2050W: The ejbPassivate() method must exist (EJB 2.0: 7.5.1).
- CHKJ2017E: This class must implement javax.ejb.SessionBean (EJB 2.0: 
 7.5.1, 7.10.2).
- CHKJ2050W: The ejbCreate() method must exist (EJB 2.0: 7.8).
- CHKJ2050W: The ejbRemove() method must exist (EJB 2.0: 4.2.2, 7.5.1).
```

Here is my Ejb class:

```
@Stateless(name = "AccBeanRemote")
public class AccBean implements AccBeanRemote{

   @Inject
   FikFacade fikFacade;

   @Inject
   OthersFacade othersFacade;
   ...
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have an ejb-jar.xml file that defines this class as a `Stateful` bean, which would require these methods to exist.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'm defining it as a `Stateless` bean too in the ejb-jar.xml

Comment: Check your project configuration, seems Eclipse validates it against EJB2.0 spec. Also you do not need to use ejb-jar.xml, since it's optional for EJB3. Keep in mind that [configuration in the ejb-jar.xml file overrides annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejdev003.htm#CCHIHIGI) (see ["Overriding Annotations With Deployment Descriptor Entries"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs001.htm#CIHDGGBF)).

Comment: @devmind Where to check the project's validation configuration ?

Comment: @user771221 I don't use Eclipse, so have no idea, sorry. I believe you can select EJB spec version when creating EJB project, so probably you have something in project settings, if any.